# Where to declare a struct operator overloading

Tags: c++, boost, struct, operator-overloading

I'm newbie in C++ (I came from C#).

I have this struct inside a namespace:

```
#pragma once

namespace utils { 

    struct astTime
    {
        int hour;
        int min;
        double secs;
    };

    double round(double number, int decPlace);
}
```

I have also a source file where I have implemented `round` function.

To use that struct in a Boost Test, I have defined these two operators inside the boost test file (.cpp):

```
namespace utils {
    bool operator ==(utils::astTime const &left, utils::astTime const &right)
    {
        return(
            left.secs == right.secs
            && left.min == right.min
            && left.hour == right.hour);
    }

    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const utils::astTime& dt)
    {
        os << dt.hour << "h " << dt.min << "m " << dt.secs << "s" << std::endl;

        return os;
    }
}
```

Where do I have to declare these two operators (and how)?

I have moved it to the header file (because **I DON'T KNOW WHERE TO DECLARE IT**), removing them from the boost test source file, this way:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

namespace utils { 

    struct astTime
    {
        int hour;
        int min;
        double secs;
    };

    bool operator ==(utils::astTime const &left, utils::astTime const &right)
    {
        return(
            left.secs == right.secs
            && left.min == right.min
            && left.hour == right.hour);
    }

    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const utils::astTime& dt)
    {
        os << dt.hour << "h " << dt.min << "m " << dt.secs << "s" << std::endl;

        return os;
    }

    double round(double number, int decPlace);
}
```

And I get the following error:

> warning LNK4006: "class std::basic_ostream > & __cdecl utils::operator<<(class
>   std::basic_ostream > &,struct
>   utils::astTime const &)"
>   (??6utils@@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV12@ABUastTime@0@@Z)
>   already defined in Utils.obj; second definition ignored

Comment: If definitions are moved in header, add `inline` to avoid ODR violation.

Comment: What was wrong with the first version? It should work. For the second one, you shouldn't define functions in header files (or make sure One Definition Rule is fulfilled somehow, e.g. by making them `inline`).

Comment: @Jarod42 I have moved to the header file because I don't know where to declare it.

Comment: You can have only **declarations** there.(`bool operator ==(utils::astTime const &left, utils::astTime const &right); std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const utils::astTime& dt);`) as you do for `double round(double number, int decPlace);`.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Sorry, I've just started to learn C++. I have moved it to the header file because I don't know where to declare it and because I need these operators in another Boost Test CPP files.

Comment: @Vans Yeah, it's fine that you don't know where to declare them. But given what we know, your first version was fine - you declared them in the same namespace as the structure they use. If you had compiler errors with that version, you should add them. Currently, **your question contains 2 questions** - "*why first version didn't work?*" (missing [mcve] here) and "*why second version didn't work?*" (defining functions in header file is tricky thing, we can answer that, but you probably didn't want to put the functions in header)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re mixing up declaration and definition in your code. Put the *definitions* into the implementation file (`*.cpp`). Put the *declarations* into the header, next to your declaration of `round`.

Alternatively, you *could* put the definitions into the header and declare them [`inline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline) (and this is routine for short functions such as custom operators). The `inline` specifier on functions prevents functions from violating the [One Definition Rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#One_Definition_Rule) when included by multiple translation units.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, when writing a class, you would *declare* all operators in the same header and namespace as the class. This allows all users of the class to have the same set of operators available on the objects of the class. There may be exceptions to this rule (e.g. to have IO operators in a separate header to reduce compile times), but the general rule of thumb stands.

Whether you also *define* operators in the header or not is a separate question. Typically, you provide definitions in headers when they are lightweight and are desirable to be inlined at the call site. Also, you normally provide definitions in the header if the operators are templates.

Your linker error is because your operator *definition* is in the header, which is included in multiple translation units (.cpp files). Effectively, this means that the definition is duplicated in multiple translation units comprising the program, which violates [ODR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule). To fix this, you can mark the operator with `inline`, which will allow the compiler to use just one of the multiple definitions in the final program (that is in case if it is not inlined in every call site).